# celebration animation in android studio

Tags: android

I am developing a small stone paper scissor game. Only one mode - user vs computer.

If the user wins.. in the last activity i want to display "USER WINS". 
This much is done.

I want to display ribbons animation all over the screen, overlapping the "USER WINS" text. 
How do I code that?

Answer (score 4):

i have found this lib for your requirement

follow [here](https://github.com/DanielMartinus/Konfetti)

tip: try to search before asking questions

how to implement

import gradle

```
 implementation 'nl.dionsegijn:konfetti:1.1.2'
```

and in you java

```
viewKonfetti.build()
.addColors(Color.YELLOW, Color.GREEN, Color.MAGENTA)
.setDirection(0.0, 359.0)
.setSpeed(1f, 5f)
.setFadeOutEnabled(true)
.setTimeToLive(2000L)
.addShapes(Shape.RECT, Shape.CIRCLE)
.addSizes(new Size(12, 5))
.setPosition(-50f, viewKonfetti.getWidth() + 50f, -50f, -50f)
.streamFor(300, 5000L)
```

add this to your xml

```
<nl.dionsegijn.konfetti.KonfettiView
    android:id="@+id/viewKonfetti"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Comment: It is throwing error on 'viewKonfetti' , 'RECT' , 'CIRCLE'.  I am seeing this thing for the first time.. so not able to comprehend it. So plz.. if you can help me solve those errors. :)

Comment: have you added implementation 'nl.dionsegijn:konfetti:1.1.2' to app:gradle?

Comment: yess.. added it in dependencies of build.gradle (Module:app)

Comment: what is the error then? can you show me screenshot? or something else?

Comment: 1:56 Gradle sync failed: Could not find method implementation() for arguments [nl.dionsegijn:konfetti:1.1.2] on root project 'advanced_game' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
  Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (753ms)

Comment: How do I paste the code like you have pasted it? The one you pasted above..xml java and gradle file. Its my second day on stack overflow.. so sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: use shortcut ctrl+k then paste it

Comment: i got it, for while just decrease the version of that lib 'nl.dionsegijn:konfetti:1.0'

Comment: if will work, i have implemented this before, in the new version they have removed something, need to check it out. you use v1.0 is perfect

Comment: ctrl+k works for editor  for answer or question, in comment box you can directly paste it

Comment: `dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'nl.dionsegijn:konfetti:1.0'
}
`

Comment: cannot resolve symbol 'viewKonfetti', 'RECT' , 'CIRCLE'

Comment: Am still waiting. :)

Comment: use Shape.Square.INSTANCE, Shape.Circle.INSTANCE instead